# New PnP Team site PowerShell does not add Owners

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, team-sites, office-365-groups

I was trying to create new Site collection in my SharePoint online tenant with O365 group. So I have come across following commands from PnP PowerShell.

[`New-PnPSite`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/new-pnpsite?view=sharepoint-ps) allows us to create O365 group with Site Collection. So I was trying to create multiple site collection from CSV. That CSV does contain information about Owners of the site. So when I try following command after authenticating to `PnPOnline` single line code works as below:

```
New-PnPSite -Type TeamSite -Title "0ABC Test" -Alias "0abctest" -Description "some desc" -Owners "user1@mytenant.com","user2@mytenant.com","user3@mytenant.com" -Lcid 1033
```

Above code will create new O365 group and also adds those user mentioned as a owner of the group. This command will also create site collection.

But when I try it by reading Owners from CSV file as below (Sample CSV):

```
DisplayName,Alias,EmailAddresses,OWNERS,AccessType
122 Dev Test,122DevProject,122DevProject@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com,"user1@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com";"user2@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com";"user3@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com",Private
```

new site never adds owner, it always shows empty.
Below is my PS Code:

```
foreach ($row in $table) #$table is my CSV object
{ 
    [array]$owners = $row.OWNERS.split(";")
    [string]$stringOwners = $null
    $stringOwners = '"{0}' -F ($owners -join '",')
    $stringOwners = $stringOwners.Replace('""', '"')
    $stringOwners = $stringOwners.Trim(',')

    New-PnPSite -Type TeamSite -Title $row.DisplayName -Alias $row.Alias -Description $row.DisplayName -Owners $stringOwners -Lcid 1033
}
```

So my question is how can we add multiple user for `New-PnPSite` reading owners from CSV file. Is this really possible? Am I missing something here?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The type for -Owners parameter should be String[].

You could try the below script:

```
 {
    [String[]]$owners= $row.OWNERS.replace('"','').split(";")
 New-PnPSite -Type TeamSite -Title $row.DisplayName -Alias $row.Alias -Description $row.DisplayName -Owners $owners -Lcid 1033
}
```

The $owners value should be like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Michael but when I tried this it didn't add users to the Group. Group was empty.

Comment: Hi, I just tested on my end. This worked for me. Users are added to the Ownwers Group. What's the value of $ownwes? Please check my updated answer, the value should be like that.